# QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings is GONE in Qt5

Tags: unicode, qt5

All displayed text in my project is in Greek. I didn't use `tr()`, just Greek characters directly. And for the correct encoding I was using:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO 8859-7"));//for Greek
```

Qt5 took `setCodecForCStrings` away , and all the characters are displayed as `"???????"`. Is there a workaround?

Please note this is a big project, I want to avoid using code for every string in the 
program.

Comment: Prefer UTF-8, it can represent all characters. `???????` is a sign of lossy encoding conversion, when the target encoding couldn't represent the character being converted. You can fix this by using UTF-8, which can represent all characters.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you Esailija

So saving all my files with UTF-8 encoding solved the problem.

If you are using Qt Creator, change the default encoding to UTF-8:
Preferences -> Text Editor -> Default Encoding ... choose UTF-8
Then for the existing files go to Edit->Select Encoding and change it to UTF-8

also for anyone wanting more details look here http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/05/source-code-must-be-utf-8-and-qstring-wants-it/