# Replacement for QTextCodec::setCodecforCStrings in Qt5

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5, porting

I have a lot of legacy that was making use of QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings to handle other languages such as portuguese, swedish and italian. I know of this solution:

- [QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings is GONE in Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968734/qtextcodecsetcodecforcstrings-is-gone-in-qt5)

And have also read that blog

- http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/05/source-code-must-be-utf-8-and-qstring-wants-it/

but it does not help at all. The fact that this function is gone really is a dealbreaker for me.

I have considered writing my own QString class or copying the source code for SetCodecForCStrings and adapting it for Qt5. I will deal with cross-platform issues (it was already dealt with anyway).

Has anyone tried this ? If so what problem did you encounter ? Is there anything already made that could be used instead (library, wrapper, adapter) ? I do not mind paying for it if I need to. Or maybe I just have to stick with qt4 but I really like the new connect syntax...

Edit :

```
int main(int argv, char** args)
{
  // Create test application.
  QApplication application(argv, args);

  QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("GB18030-0"));

  //My main form shown here

  return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: The question would be where in your source code are you relying on changing the text codec? Can you isolate those parts and make them go through `QTextCodec` instead?

Comment: @peppe Well pretty much everywhere qt is. Switching to QTextCoded would require about the same amount of time as switching the code to utf-8. But I take it from your comment there is no way for me to get qt5 if I cannot get rid of SetCodecForCStrings.

Comment: Still you haven't explained how exactly in your code you're using `setCodecForCStrings`. Can you add a SSSCE?